# Error: Router cannot be used as a jsx component

Tags: reactjs, jsx, tsx

What is wrong with this code?

```
    <Router>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Redirect to="/tab" />
      </Route>
      {loading ? (
        <Loader style={{ margin: 100 }} />
      ) : (
        <>
          <Route exact path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
          <Route exact path="/termsofuse" component={TermsOfUse} />
          <Route exact path="/tab" component={Tab} />
          <Route exact path="/config" component={TabConfig} />
          </>
      )}
      
    </Router>
```

Dependencies
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@types/node": "^12.0.0",
"@types/react": "^16.14.6",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.9.12",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
"cross-env": "^7.0.3",
"env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
},
"resolutions":{
"@types/react": "^17.0.2",
"@types/react-dom": "^17.0.2"
},

Comment: You couldn't return JSX in the router because it's only accessing the Route that's why you have to return Route in this section or you won't show loader on this then add lazy loading suspense to add loader on this.

Comment: Hi, This is my code can you show some fixes to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import all components using lazy loading and add suspense to handle routes error if it happens then add your loader code in suspense to handle it.

```js
//import your all pages using lazy loading
const Privacy = React.lazy(() => import('./Privacy'));

  <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
     <Router>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Redirect to="/tab" />
      </Route>
        <Route exact path="/privacy" component={Privacy} />
        <Route exact path="/termsofuse" component={TermsOfUse} />
        <Route exact path="/tab" component={Tab} />
        <Route exact path="/config" component={TabConfig} />
      </Router>
    </Suspense>
```